# android post data to server when slow connection

Tags: android

my data is send to server when connection is fast but when connection is weak or slow the data is not send i want to send data when connection is slow or how can i wait till the connection is fast and then post data to server
below is my code

```
class sendMessageN extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String mess="no mess",subjector="";
    Spanned old_message;
    int check_no1,success=0;
    String error = null;
    public sendMessageN(Spanned newMessage, String subjects,int check_no) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mess = Html.toHtml(newMessage);
        subjector = subjects;
        old_message = newMessage;
        check_no1 = check_no;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sender",myAcc));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reciever",filename));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",mess+""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject",subjector));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_no",check_no1-1+""));
        for(int i=0;i < 10;i++){
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(send_text);
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            int some_reasonable_timeout = (int) (30 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            try
            {
                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
                if (status.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                {
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    error = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
                    success = 1;
                } else {

                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // Do something else, if wanted.
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Do something else, if wanted.
            } finally {
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
            if(success == 1){
                i = 10; 
            }
            if(i == 9 && success == 0){
                resend_message(old_message,subjector,check_no1);    
            }
        }
        return error; 
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result != null){
            if (success == 1) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check connection before posting data on server.

Firstly check internet connection is available or not from this method.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean connected = false;
        ConnectivityManager mConnManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (mConnManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = mConnManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo mNetInfo : netInfo) {
                if ((mNetInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") || mNetInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        "MOBILE"))
                        && mNetInfo.isConnected()) {
                    Log.d("", "========== ||  CONNECTION AVAILABLE  || =========");
                    connected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return connected;
    }
```

If internet connection is available then check network status and then post data to server!

```
public static byte getNetworkStatus(Context context) {
        byte networkStatus = NETWORK_NOT_AVAILABLE;
        ConnectivityManager mConnManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (mConnManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = mConnManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo mNetInfo : netInfo) {
                if ((mNetInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") || mNetInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        "MOBILE"))
                        && mNetInfo.isConnected()) {
                    networkStatus = NETWORK_AVAILABLE;
                    Log.d("", "========== ||  CONNECTION AVAILABLE  || =========");

                }
            }
        }
        if (networkStatus == NETWORK_NOT_AVAILABLE
                && (Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0)) {
            networkStatus = AIRPLANE_MODE_ON;
        }
        return networkStatus;
    }
```

Comment: and if the post data is not send due to slow connection how to resend data

Comment: If coonection is slow then store those data in Sqlite and networkadapter and check network on regular interval and then send data to server...Otherwise i will suggest to use syncadapter..

Comment: plz can you give me example or any link of  syncadapter plz. and thanks for the info